# R - ggplot2 geom_line dodge

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am having trouble drawing "dodges" `line` on "dodged" `stacked bars`.

```
dt = mtcars %>% group_by(am, cyl) %>% summarise(m = mean(disp))
dt0 = dt[dt$am == 0, ]
dt1 = dt[dt$am == 1, ]

dt0 %>% ggplot(aes(factor(cyl), m, fill = factor(cyl))) + geom_bar(stat = 'identity', position = 'dodge') +
  geom_point(data = dt1, aes(factor(cyl), m, colour = factor(cyl)), position=position_dodge(width=0.9), colour = 'black')
```

[image]

What I would like is to draw a line from the top of the stacked bar to the black **points** of each `cyl`.

```
dt0 %>% ggplot(aes(factor(cyl), m, fill = factor(cyl))) + geom_bar(stat = 'identity', position = 'dodge') +
  geom_point(data = dt1, aes(factor(cyl), m, colour = factor(cyl)), position=position_dodge(width=0.9), colour = 'black') + 
  geom_line(data = dt1, aes(factor(cyl), m, colour = factor(cyl), group = 1), position=position_dodge(width=0.9), colour = 'black')
```

However, the `position=position_dodge(width=0.9)` dodge doesn't work here.

Any idea ?

Comment: Try to use a `geom_segment()`.

Comment: it doesn't solve the `dodge` issue unfortunately

Comment: So, this is not what you want? `geom_segment(x = aes(factor(cyl), y = dt0$m, xend = factor(cyl), yend = dt1$m))`

Comment: sorry your code isn't working. `Error: geom_segment requires the following missing aesthetics: xend, yend` thanks

Comment: Try `geom_segment(aes(x=factor(cyl), y = dt0$m, xend = factor(cyl), yend = dt1$m))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is much easier to accomplish if you reshape your summary data:

```
dt <- mtcars %>% 
    group_by(am, cyl) %>% 
    summarise(m = mean(disp)) %>% 
    spread(am, m)

    cyl        0        1
* <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
1     4 135.8667  93.6125
2     6 204.5500 155.0000
3     8 357.6167 326.0000
```

While "0" and "1" are poor column names, they can still be used in `aes()` if you quote them in backticks. The calls to `position_dodge()` also become unnecessary:

```
dt %>% ggplot(aes(x = factor(cyl), y = `0`, fill = factor(cyl))) + 
    geom_bar(stat = 'identity') +
    geom_point(aes(x = factor(cyl), y = `1`), colour = 'black') +
    geom_segment(aes(x = factor(cyl), xend = factor(cyl), y = `0`, yend = `1`))
```

[image]